# android-ndk - using prebuilt static libraries that links with each other

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I've got 3 prebuilt static libraries I want to use in my shared library.

The problem is when the `ndk-build` tries to link to the static libraries, I get tons of undefined references thrown at me. 
The 'undefined references' originates from when the static libraries tries to call methods in another static library. For example, tinyNET calling a method in tinySAK.  The dependencies are this: 
tinySAK has no dependencies
tinyNET depends on tinySAK, 
tinyHTTP depends on tinyNET and tinySAK

Here's what my Android.mk looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# TINYSAK
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinySAK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinySAK_armv7-a.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


# TINYNET
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinyNET
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinyNET_armv7-a.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)



# TINYHTTP
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tinyHTTP
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libtinyHTTP_armv7-a.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)





include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libtest

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
/../../testclient.cpp \
/../../main.cpp \
/../../Webservice.cpp 

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../includes/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyHTTP/include/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinySAK/src/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../doubango/tinyNET/src/ 

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := tinySAK tinyNET tinyHTTP

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My god, it was so simple. 
To any of you with the same problem, heres how I solved it:

Instead of

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := tinySAK tinyNET tinyHTTP
```

Use

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := tinyHTTP tinyNET tinySAK
```

meaning, the one with the most dependencies first.